# How to create multiple language in other activity?

Tags: android, multiple-languages

In other question i have answer to create multiple language. But not used in all activity/pages aplications.  How to change language in other activity/page?

i have code to main activity/page only, how to create in other activity/page?

i use this code to change language:

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
    super.attachBaseContext(LocaleHelper.onAttach(newBase, "en"));
}

private void updateView(String lang) {
    Context context = LocaleHelper.setLocale(this, lang);
    Resources resources = context.getResources();

    navigation_view.getMenu().findItem(R.id.account).setTitle(resources.getString(R.string.menuAccount));
    navigation_view.getMenu().findItem(R.id.settingPassword).setTitle(resources.getString(R.string.menuSettingPass));
    navigation_view.getMenu().findItem(R.id.about).setTitle(resources.getString(R.string.menuAbout));
    navigation_view.getMenu().findItem(R.id.logout).setTitle(resources.getString(R.string.menuLogout));
    navigation_view.getMenu().findItem(R.id.login).setTitle(resources.getString(R.string.menuLogin));
}
```

and i use this triger to change language:

```
Paper.book().write("language", "id");
updateView((String)Paper.book().read("language"));
navigation_view.getMenu().findItem(R.id.language_in).setVisible(false);
navigation_view.getMenu().findItem(R.id.language_en).setVisible(true);
```

source code from :
[source code full from EDMT Dev](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ywF-ySiBAsc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put your string resources in different folders:

- /res/values/strings.xml
- /res/values-en/strings.xml
- /res/values-es/strings.xml
- /res/values-jp/strings.xml

System will automatically loads proper string resource based on your locale. 
You need to have `attachBaseContext` method in all your activities. For cleaner code, you can create a `BaseActivity` class with `attachBaseContext` method and extend all your activities from this base class:

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
        super.attachBaseContext(LocaleHelper.onAttach(newBase, "en"));
    }
    // ...
}

public class MyActivity extends BaseActivity {
    // ...
    private void updateView(String lang) {
        // all your code
    }
}
```

Comment: how to change language in other activity/page, because that code only can use in main activity?

Comment: @dyantb `... because that code only can use in main activity` Where did you read / who told you that?!

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ywF-ySiBAsc

Comment: @dyantb Can't use YouTube right now. However, if they said so, **they lied**! It's like saying that you can't use a drawable other than in the main Activity!! Please learn the basics of Android internalization (and of Android resources in general).

Comment: @Kling Klang, the tutorial only provides information for 1 main page, and my question is, how to change/multiple language in other page? not in main activity only

Comment: @dyantb As I said, please learn the basics of Android internalization (and of Android resources in general). OBVIOUSLY ENOUGH, resources can be accessed EVERYWHERE in your app, not only in your main Activity.

Answer (score 0):

create a new Context with properly configured Resources and put it as a base one for Application and Activity via attachBaseContext.

```
public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
       super.attachBaseContext(LocaleHelper.setLocale(base));
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
       super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
       LocaleManager.setLocale(this);
    }
...
```

}

A base activity for other activities

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      .....
   }
```

Comment: and then how to change language in other activity/page? please help me